# Android emulator doesn't work in Titanium

Tags: android-emulator, titanium-mobile

I'm just starting with Titanium SDK and created a android project. When the project is done and i want to run the code in emulator titanum gives the following error.

```
     File 

    "C:\Users\navidos\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 2324, in <module>
        builder = Builder(project_name,sdk_dir,project_dir,template_dir,app_id)
      File "C:\Users\navidos\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 341, in __init__
        self.sdk = AndroidSDK(sdk, self.tool_api_level)
      File "C:\Users\navidos\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\androidsdk.py", line 49, in __init__
        self.set_api_level(api_level)
      File "C:\Users\navidos\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\androidsdk.py", line 53, in set_api_level
        self.find_platform_dir()
      File "C:\Users\navidos\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\androidsdk.py", line 131, in find_platform_dir
        raise Exception("No \"%s\" or \"%s\" in the Android SDK" % ('android-%s' % api_level, android_api_levels[api_level]))

Exception: No "android-8" or "android-2.2" in the Android SDK
```

Is there someone who knows what i'm doing wrong because i just don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download the appropriate Android sdk (through the [Android SDK Manager](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html), console, or third party tool) and install it.  Check out this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961445/how-to-resolve-titanium-error-ex-tion-no-android-8-or-android-2-2-in-t).

Comment: GrailsGuy i'm sorry my fault i was to late to undo the post, saw that to late. Tnx for fast repley though.

Comment: @Navid No problem, maybe it will help someone else in the future.